# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 10

Tags: php, foreach, warnings

Code needs to return `"alex"` but it returns:

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

I can't find a solution so I'm asking for help.

index.php:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

if (!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {

    foreach ($user->results() as $user ) {
        echo $user->username, '<>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($user->results())`

Comment: Try using `$user` directly in foreach instead of `$user->results()`.

Comment: var_dump $user->results()s before the if statement and see if you get anything you are probably not getting results back (also if you are following along with codecourse OOP login course you should be using $user->first() to get back the 1 result)

Comment: maybe assign $user->results() to a variable then use that in the foreach

Comment: It retuns same warning.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju Notice: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object

Comment: Then You need to use the !empty($user->results()) just as mentioned below in the solution by @anjali

Comment: @AviTeller
When I var_dump :
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

 var_dump($user->results());
if(!$user->count()) {
 
echo 'No user';
} else {
    foreach($user->results() as $user ) {
  echo $user->username, '<>';
  
 }
result is:
NULL
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @KishenNagaraju-It returns"no user" but it needs to return "alex"

Comment: the reason you are getting an invalid warning is because there are no results coming back from the db is there an alex entry in the database?

Comment: @AviTeller Of course its in database

Comment: the error is because you have no data returning and the function count is still there you have to do if($user->count() < 1)  instead and you will echo no user

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
    $user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

if(!$user->count()) {
echo 'No user';
} else {
    if(!empty($user->results())){
        foreach($user->results() as $user ) {
            echo $user->username, '<>';

        }
   }

}
```

Comment: This isn't right either. You return a "no user" messages based on a condition of one thing but then potentially return no message or output based of another. `if (!$user->count() || empty($user->results()) ) { echo "no user"; } else {`

Comment: @Anjali Patil - that returns nothing (blank page)

Comment: @James -that returns "no user".

Comment: Please, provide output from $user->count() & $user->results() so that we get clear idea of response .

Comment: @AnjaliPatil $user->count() returns "1" (one)

Comment: what is the output of  var_dump($user->results());

Comment: @AnjaliPatil - I pasted db.php beneath

Comment: @AnjaliPatil        var_dump($user->results()); before foreach is NULL

Comment: Check out is user available in database with username = "alex" ? Or you have issue with your query.

Comment: @AnjaliPatil "alex is in database, please check db.php . I vcant find isseu with query,

Comment: @SymfonyBeginer OF course it returns no user, you have no user. Do you want to show the "no user" message if there's no user count, but let go past the "no user" message and then check if the array is empty and do nothing if it is? Makes no sense. Check all possible things that could be wrong, show a message, else everything must be ok to proceed (as per my original comment). This IMO is good programming

Answer (score 0):

this is a db.php

```
 class DB {
     private static $_instance = null;
     private $_pdo,
             $_query,
             $_error = false,
             $_results,
             $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {

        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));

        }  catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }   

    } 

    public static function getInstance() {
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
                self::$_instance = new DB();

            }
            return self::$_instance;
 }

    public function query($sql,  $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;

                }   

            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {

                $this->_error = true;

            }

        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=','>','<','>=' ,'<=');


            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];


            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;

                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *' , $table, $where);


    }


    public function delete ($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE ' , $table, $where);


    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;

    }


    public function error() {

        return $this->_error;

    }
    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake . It way typo in line 43 of db.php

```
I wrote : $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

It need to be:

```
$this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I missed "s" in results.
Tkanks for helping.